# Is there one word for knowledge and wisdom that has been obtained from different sources and from experience?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is there one word for "gathered wisdom", meaning knowledge and wisdom that has been obtained from different sources and from experience?

Comment: *Accumulated wisdom* or *collected wisdom* are the generally used terms for this.

Comment: *Experience* is gathered knowledge of observed events. Wisdom is how you apply that experience. There isn't *really* gathered wisdom. (personal viewpoint) IMO, wisdom isn't really wisdom until it's applied. It can't be gathered or held or stored.

Comment: BTW, I'm not saying it's impossible to have a collection of or remember wise things other people have said or done, but it's not *your* wisdom (analogous to *your* experience) until it's applied.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion:
lore - knowledge gained through study or experience.

The definition is from Merriam Webster's dictionary. There are several other words which you may use depending on context and audience.